# JavaFX  character in Button not properly displaying

Tags: javafx, encoding, utf-8

There is what seems to be an encoding issue with UTF8, on my preproduction machine, that I cannot replicate on my development machine.

With the following FXML:

```
<Button fx:id="searchButton" defaultButton="true" text="  Go !" />
```

Or with the following Java:

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    ...
    searchButton.setText(" \ud83d\udd0d Go !");
    ...
}
```

I see the following on my development machine, both in Eclipse and with a exe native package[image: Expected output]

However, when running the native package (or even the JAR directly) on the production environment, I see the following[image: Irregular output on production] If I change the code to `searchButton.setText("\ud83d\udd0d");`, I then see this:[image]

As you can see, there is a strange square appearing, while the "" shows properly.

It might be worth noting that the production machine is a Windows Server 2008 running 1.8.0_31 JRE, which motivated the packaging of the 1.8.0_101 from the development machine, into the native package.

What could be causing such a problem ?

Comment: Ever solve this problem?